# Only Require input to be filled if other inputs are not filled

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET application which requires the user to fill in a form to create a new object. It is defined as follows:

```
public class Address
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }

        public string AirportCode { get; set; }
    }
```

The fields `AddressLine1` and `City` are required when filling out the `create` form. However, a new development has introduced the field `AirportCode`, which changes the requirements. Basically, if an airport code value is given, no other values are required. If not, the address line 1 and city values are *both* still required. If the user neglected to fill out any of the form, I would expect all three fields to display an error message until wither the `City` and `AddressLine1` values or the `AirportCode` value was given, but I can worry asbout the semantics of it later - the important thing is to not let an invalid object get through.

I guess the logic would be:

```
if AirportCode OR (AddressLine1 AND City)
```

Here is a small sample of the `City` input field. It's the default generated by the application:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="City" class="col-md-2 control-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to go about implementing this without resorting to JavaScript? The form validation has been so neat and easy so far, and I would love to be able to do this through the framework. Thanks.

**An afterthought:** I may later on want to grey out the other fields if `AirportCode` started getting filled out. It's not strictly related to validation but it might tie into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write your own custom validation attribute.

Howerver there is a plugin called "ExpressiveAnnotations" which is very easy to use and helps you implement logic into your "DataAnnotations".

```
[RequiredIf("AirportCode == null",
    ErrorMessage = "Your error message.")]
public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("AirportCode == null",
    ErrorMessage = "Your error message.")]
public string City { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("City == null")]
[RequiredIf("AddressLine1 == null")]
public string AirportCode { get; set; }
```

If you feel it would be useful for your purposes, more information about ExpressiveAnnotations library can be found [here](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations). Client side validation is also supported out of the box.

> A small .NET and JavaScript library which provides annotation-based
>   conditional validation mechanisms. Given attributes allow to forget
>   about imperative way of step-by-step verification of validation
>   conditions in many cases. Since fields validation requirements are
>   applied as metadata, domain-related code is more condensed.

Comment: I don't think ExpressiveAnnotations supports asp.net core yet https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations/issues/90

Comment: He doesn't say that he is using Core, does he?

Comment: his question is tagged as asp.net-core and the code he shows is clearly asp.net core using taghelpers in the view

Comment: Your right. Yeah then he would have to write his own custom validation attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway - ExpressiveAnnotations looks like a really good plugin and I intend to use it in future development if the opportunity arises. I managed to get the functionality I was looking fro with custom validation attributes.

Comment: Glad to help! Good question though.